# Adding a row spanning column header to a knitr kable table

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

kableExtra can add header rows with items spanning multiple columns in tables produces with kable

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
mat <- matrix(1:4,2,dimnames=list(c("a","b"),c("x","y")))
mat %>% kable("html") %>% add_header_above(c(" " = 1,"row header" = 2))
```

[image: table with row header]

I would like to have a column header also, like this:

[image: table with row and column header]

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can do it but i found a way to fix your issue

```
mat <- data.frame(a = c("row header","row header"),b = c("a","b"),c = c("x","y"))
mat %>% kable("html") %>% add_header_above(c(" " = 1,"row header" = 2))



kable(mat, align = "c",col.names = c("","","")) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left",font_size = 12)%>%
column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle")%>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "row header" = 2))
```

i hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Building on what you told me I was able to solve my problem completely:

```
mat <- data.frame(a = c("column header","column header"),b = c("a","b"),c = c("x","y"))
kable(mat, align = "c",col.names = c("","","")) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left",font_size = 12)%>%
column_spec(1, bold = T,width="3em",extra_css="transform: rotate(-90deg);") %>%
collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle")%>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "row header" = 2))
```